# Dynamic height button with gradient and pointed end

Tags: css

I would like to create buttons with gradient as the background and a pointed end that will adjust to the height of the button, which depends on the amount of text inside. Page background can vary, so I can't use solid color for pointed end. The best solution I came up with is using after pseudo-element with svg code as a background-image, setting the background height to 100%, but this solution does not satisfy me too much, because I don't know if it will look good on all modern browsers. Do you have any ideas? Maybe I should use Javascript?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Button example</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    .wrapper {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 15px;
      max-width: 180px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .btn {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      background: #000000 linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #666666);
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 8px 20px;
      margin-right: 12px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    }

    .btn::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: -12px;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 13px;
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='13' height='40'%3E%3ClinearGradient id='css-btn-example' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='6.5' y1='40' x2='6.5'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23666'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cpath fill='url(%23css-btn-example)' d='M0 0h1l12 20L1 40H0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      background-size: 13px 100%;
    }

    .btn:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="btn">One line</div>
    <div class="btn">Two line button example</div>
    <div class="btn">Three line button long example</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your code.

Comment: @KoshVery I've added my code, thanks for reminder

Comment: Thanks, it helps other people too.

Answer (score 1):

In case the gradient will always be from top to bottom (or bottom to top), you can consider some trick using skew like below. The idea is to use the pseudo elements where you apply two different gradient that will intersect at the same color creating the illusion of one gradient.

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, #4100bf);
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, purple, #4100bf);
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text here
</div>
<div class="box">
  Some text here Some text here
</div>
```

Another idea without transparency is to consider mutilple background and hide the gradient with a white color (or any color of the background). You can then consider any kind of gradient, even a radial-gradient.

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  margin:5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 48%,#fff 50%) bottom right/20px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 48%,#fff 50%) top right/20px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, blue,purple);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text here
</div>
<div class="box">
  Some text here Some text here
</div>
```

You have also the clip-path solution:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, purple);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 20px) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 20px) 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 20px) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 20px) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text here
</div>
<div class="box">
  Some text here Some text here
</div>
```

Comment: Second solution is very good for page with one background, thank you :)